# Recomendations of Word-to-PDF with high quality and keeping hyperlinks?

Tags: pdf, images, image-quality, microsoft-word

I want to save a Word (2016) as a PDF but keeping the native **high quality of images** and **text hyperlinks**. Currently I am able to do only one of those at once: I can retain hyperlinks if I use the default word-to-PDF save from Microsoft Word, but the image quality is not good at all; or I can use PDF printers like [Nitro Reader](https://www.gonitro.com/es/pdf-reader) or [PDFcreator](https://pdfcreator.es/) who allow me to keep a really good image quality but do not retain hyperlinks.

Does anyone know a way to maximize image quality for the default PDF saver? If not, someone knows about a PDF printer that also saves hyperlinks embedded in the text?

Comment: How about reinserting the links to PDF? Many PDF readers allow such edits.

Comment: Yeah that's the solution I came up with. It's the only way I found to retain high quality of images without anything moving. Nonetheless... inserting a hundred hyperlinks after printing the PDF will be kind of a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Open your word file in LibreOffice Writer (freeware, portable version exists, it needs no installation) If your file is simple enough it can be recognized well. Export as PDF. Hyperlinks are transferred to PDF.

There's numerous export options, one of them is to select image DPI in PDF. Direct export leaves all as is.

BTW I haven't your Word version. But try to export there at first, do not print.

**ADD due a comment**:

In the comment occurs name Illustrator. That hints you have access to Adobes software. If the accessible set contains InDesign try to place the Word document to a blank InD layout. I have done it recently and the hyperlinks came along. It's possible to keep all styles and page breaks.See he placing options.

Export as interactive PDF with 300Dpi image resolution keeps photos good looking. Vectors are exported as vectors if nothing is wanted to be rasterized.

Comment: That was a really good idea, and so I tried. LibreOffice handled SVG and EMF images really well and lost no quality whatsoever. Nevertheless, when used EMF some minor details changed (dashed lines turned solid, or a layer was in front of another one mistakenly). And when exporting images from illustrator into SVG I still have the same problem: again a little size change in some images messes everything. So I think I will keep with my "shitty" solution... print into PDFCreator and then put the hyperlinks one by one. Thank you anyway for your idea, @user287001.